# I'm new.. i usually have a lot of questions... can this site help?

Tags: discussion

How does this work? Can I ask any question and you will answer me? How long does it take to get an answer?

And by the way: if this is what I think it is, you have just became my new English teacher/s :D — because I need to get better in English if I want to go study in America or the UK. :D

Comment: Please read the FAQ linked at the top of the page, and see if that helps.

Comment: This question was migrated from main to meta. Each has its own FAQ. The one to read is the main FAQ at http://english.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 10):

> How does this work?

Sometimes well, sometimes not. By and large, the more you put into it, the more you get out of it. Everybody who answers questions here does it for fun, so you need to meet us halfway. If you follow ordinary conventions of punctuation and spelling (and capitalization), write complete sentences, format neatly, and take the time to provide enough detail and context that we don’t have to guess what you’re looking for, you’ll get an answer—probably several—***provided that*** . . .

> Can I ask any question and you will answer me?

. . . ***your question fits the requirements described in the [FAQ](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq)***. In a nutshell, those requirements are that it’s got to be a question about the English language (not something else like how to write a novel or how to pick up girls which happens to involve the English language), and it has to be a real question (not a peeve, not a poll, not a dictionary lookup) to which a single answer can be provided in 200-800 words and which is ***interesting to somebody in the community***.

> How long does it take to get an answer?

Anything from thirty seconds to a couple of hours; but it’s usually worthwhile checking in every so often for a day or two, because people drop in to answer from all over the globe, at all times of day, and the last answer may be the best one.

By the way, you might want to check [this SE site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners), too, which may accommodate some of your questions more comfortably. It’s on the verge of going to “private Beta”, and if you commit now you’ll be able to participate from the very beginning. You’re welcome to participate on both sites.

Answer (score 9):

- how does this work?

The usual internet application...look around first before doing anything. Read the FAQ.

- can i ask any question and you will answer me?

Not any question. Not any question about English. Really basic questions that could be answered by taking an elementary class in English are not good here. Read the questions that have a high number of votes to see what to do, read those with a negative number to see what to avoid.

- how long does it take to get an answer?

almost all questions, within 24 hours will get some response, either an actual answer or comments or voting to close.

- btw if this is what i think it is. you have just became my new english teacher/s :D cause i need to get better in english if i wanna go study in America or UK. :D

This, EL&U, is probably not what you think it is. It is not a good replacement for a class, any number of on-line language learning programs, listening to English movies or living and speaking with native speakers. EL&U is an excellent source for small bits of explanation, and can really help language learners by letting them see explanations of certain grammatical points. It is great as an *addition* to language learning tools, but don't go to it as a first source of answers to your language questions.

Comment: _"Really basic questions that could be answered by taking an elementary class in English are not good here."_ < You may want to bring out that most of such questions are very much welcome at [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5):

You can ask any question you want. First, look in a dictionary or grammar book. If you can't find the answer, then write a question that explains what you would like to know. Make sure the question contains enough detail, so that contributors to the site can understand well what you would like to know. Sometimes, in the course of preparing your question carefully, you will discover the answer on your own.

Comment: _Any question_ is a bit excessive.